# Cloning data partition to other Android devices

Tags: android, copy, partition

We have several devices running Android in an industrial environment.
We think about completely setting up one device and then copy the whole /data directory to the other devices. The expected benefit is to configure things like wireless settings and install the required apps and updates only once on one device and somehow bring this onto the other devices.
Is this a good idea?

I am not sure if there is device specific information stored in data such as a device ID or something else that we would mess up with our idea.
Besides this what about 'uid's that are responsible to represent app permissions? Do you expect problems if our apps are not installed onto a device but simply come by a copied /data partition?
Is something specific established on a device after the first boot when /data is created and filled, that should not be replaced with something else?

Would it be better to copy only selected directories or even files? This is much more effort but ok if there is no other way...

I would appreciate any input about what can go wrong and what we should consider.

Comment: I have the very same question. So far, all my attempts and search on the net failed to get a solution. Did you find a solution?

Comment: cp -p preserves attributes. This could help to at least create a copy of important app data. I still have no reliable way to do this in a "one image for all devices" manner. As there is a lot of stuff in /data I think you should prefer to copy only selected parts of data, not the whole partition.